# Could not load type 'Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder'

Tags: helix, visual-studio

I have 1 solution for `Sitecore 9.3` with 4 projects `(ASP .Net 4.7.1 MVC)` using the `Helix principles`. I added references `Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences (9.0.180604)`, `Sitecore.MVC.NoReferences (9.0.180604)` and `Sitecore.MVC.Analytics.NoReferences (9.0.180604)` from Sitecore public Nuget Feed.

I removed `Global.asax`, App_Data, and `App_Start` from every project. Also, `Web.config` files have None as Build Action.

Everything compiles perfectly without errors, however, when I enter the site this error jumps. Could not load type `Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder`

[image: Could not load type 'Sitecore.HealthCheck.DependencyInjection.HealthChecksBuilder']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added wrong versions of nuget packages. Instead of `9.0.180604` use

https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Kernel/9.3.0

You overwrote 9.3 dlls with 9.0 dlls. They are not compatible.

If you don't need dependencies, you can use `Ignore dependencies` option, but it's gonna be easier to upgrade if you don't use `.NoReferences` packages.